# AppleScript does not work in app save window

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript that works perfectly in finder. It creates a folder named with the days date and has a shortcut key connected to it.

But it does not work when in another app, in the save window. Can you please help.

Here is the code I have.

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        if exists Finder window 1 then
            set thisPath to (the target of the front window) as alias
        else
            set thisPath to (path to desktop)
        end if
    on error
        return
    end try
end tell
set x to my the_perfect_datestring()
if x is not "-ERROR" then
    set fullPath to thisPath & x as text
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            --activate
            if not (exists fullPath) then
                set y to make new folder at thisPath with properties {name:x}
            end if
            activate
        end try
    end tell
end if

on the_perfect_datestring()
    try
        set cd to (the current date)
        set the_year to year of (cd) as number
        set the_month to month of (cd) as number
        set the_day to day of (cd) as number
        if the_month < 10 then set the_month to "0" & the_month
        if the_day < 10 then set the_day to "0" & the_day
        return ((the_year & "-" & the_month & "-" & the_day) as string)
    on error
        return "-ERROR"         

    end try
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the settings in a Save dialog box with the Finder AppleScript terminology.

The only way with AppleScript is System Events and GUI scripting. The script syntax depends strongly on the particular UI.

Answer (score 0):

To work with save dialogs in other applications, you would need to change your workflow a bit.   The save dialog works with text (the file/folder name), so you can create a text service to paste in the desired string.

To create a service, start up the Automator application and select the Service (Quick Action) document - the workflow will have settings that determine what kind of input it will accept, for example:

`Workflow receives current text in any application`

Next, check the `Output replaces selected text` box - this will replace selected text with the output of your workflow.

Drag a **Run AppleScript** action into the workflow, and completely replace the default contents with a new `Run` handler and your date string handler, for example:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  set x to the_perfect_datestring()
  if x is not "-ERROR" then return x
end run

on the_perfect_datestring()
  try
    # do your filename stuff
    tell (current date) as «class isot» as string
      return text 1 thru 10
    end tell -- or whatever
  on error
    return "-ERROR"
  end try
end the_perfect_datestring
```

After you save the workflow, the service should be available any time you select some text (in the right-click context menu).

An equivalent to your original workflow with the Finder would then be to create a new folder, and use the service on the highlighted “untitled folder” name to change it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate it. I am very new to code. Tried to place the on run code in. But no luck.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  I’ve edited my answer with more information about creating the service workflow.

Comment: Thank you. Tried. that. It works particaly. Sounds ungreatful. I can create a new folder from any app save window. And then while the text is selected. I run the script as a shortcut. Date replaces it. I would like it to create the folder as well. Can that be done.

Comment: Further testing. Text edit, Photoshop and safari it does not work. But illustrator it does.

Comment: As mentioned, there isn't any Finder terminology for accessing the panel or even seeing when it Is put up - the Save panel has a button to create new folders, I think that is about as close as you are going to get for something that works where you are wanting.  The service should work in anything that lets you edit text (if set to receive text from any app), and works for me with Safari and TextEdit in Mojave.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.